# Delete generated record from a table using a button

Tags: php, sqlsrv

I'm pretty sure this is a very frequently asked question in this community but I haven't found a post that clarified my problem.

I have a table generated by a query,so I want to have a button ("x") to remove the row the button is positioned. My code so far obeys to the form method but won't delete the record.

this is my code:

```php
<?php
include("includes/connect.php");

if(isset($_POST['procesar'])){
  $fechaDesde = $_POST['fechaDesde'];
  $fecha1 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($fechaDesde));
  $fechaHasta = $_POST['fechaHasta'];
  $fecha2 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($fechaHasta));
  $params = [
    [$fecha1,    SQLSRV_PARAM_IN],
    [$fecha2,    SQLSRV_PARAM_IN],
  ];
  $query ="{call mostrar_movimientos2(?,?)}";
  $resultado = sqlsrv_query($con, $query, $params);
if ($resultado != false){
  while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($resultado, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
    echo "<tr><th scope='row'><input class='form-control' name='idv' value='{$row['id']}' disabled></th>";
    if ($row['concepto'] != 'Cheques'){
      echo "<th scope='row'>$";
      echo "{$row['importe']}</th>";
    } else{
      echo "<th scope='row'>-$";
      echo "{$row['importe']}</th>";
    }
    
    echo "<th scope='row'>{$row['concepto']}</th>";
    echo "<th scope='row'>{$row['fecha_movimiento']}</th>";
    echo "<th scope='row'><button type='submit' name='borrar' class='btn btn-danger'>X</button></th></tr>";
  }
} else{
  echo('Algo salió mal: ');
    print_r(sqlsrv_errors());
    die();
}
if(isset($_POST['idv'])){
  $id = $_GET['idv'];
  $intid = (int)$id;
  if(isset($_POST['borrar'])){
    $queryd ="DELETE from movimientos where id = '$intid'";
    $resultadod = sqlsrv_query($con, $queryd);
    }
    }}
?>
```